# Magento 2 : How to change the cross sell text in product Edit page

Tags: magento2, product, cross-sells

i have overwritten the Related.php file but nothing happen

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related" type="Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related" />
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related
    {

     public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
     { 
       echo "test"; die;
     }
  }
?>
```

Please help  this issue.

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Related" />
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Related.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private static $sortOrder = 90;

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                static::GROUP_RELATED => [
                    'children' => [
                        $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_RELATED => $this->getRelatedFieldset(),
                        $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_UPSELL => $this->getUpSellFieldset(),
                        $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CROSSSELL => $this->getCrossSellFieldset(),
                    ],
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells'),
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => static::DATA_SCOPE,
                                'sortOrder' =>
                                    $this->getNextGroupSortOrder(
                                        $meta,
                                        self::$previousGroup,
                                        self::$sortOrder
                                    ),
                            ],
                        ],

                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    protected function getCrossSellFieldset()
    {
        $content = __(
            'These "impulse-buy" products appear next to the shopping cart' .
            ' as cross-sells to the items already in the shopping cart.'
        );

        return [
            'children' => [
                'button_set' => $this->getButtonSet(
                    $content,
                    __('Add Cross-Sell Products'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CROSSSELL
                ),
                'modal' => $this->getGenericModal(
                    __('Add Cross-Sell Products'),
                    $this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CROSSSELL
                ),
                static::DATA_SCOPE_CROSSSELL => $this->getGrid($this->scopePrefix . static::DATA_SCOPE_CROSSSELL),
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__fieldset-section',
                        'label' => __('Test Sell Products'),
                        'collapsible' => false,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'sortOrder' => 30,
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I followed as per your instruction nothing happened. still loading from vendor file.
Is this working for you?
Am using the enterprise version

Comment: ok. i will check in enterprise.

Comment: do we need to extend as like below mentioned?
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtmldi.xml

`<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="logotype" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>`

Comment: i am not try using virtualtype.best way class override using preference.

Comment: okay, please check from your end and let me know what needs to be change in preference level. Thanks